# Find the antiderivative of the following problem

Tags: integration

Find the antiderivative of $\pi(\frac{4}{y^2})$.

This has to do with a volume problem. And I'm using the disk method to solve. So the pi needs to incorporated.

Comment: What is it that is giving you trouble?

Comment: I actually just wanted to make sure my antiderivative was right. I got (4y^3)/(3) pi. The pi is included because it's part of the volume formula.

Comment: That's not right. Write it in terms of negative exponents: $4\pi y^{-2}$. Then apply the antiderivative rule for exponents.

Comment: Note that if $\alpha\ne -1$, then $\int x^\alpha \,dx=\frac{1}{1+\alpha} x^{1+\alpha}+C$. Yours is the case $\alpha=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{4\pi}{y^2}dy = 4\pi\int y^{-2}dy=4\pi\frac{y^{-1}}{-1}=-\frac{4 \pi}{y} + c $

Here $c$ is the constant of integration as the integral is indefinite.